# How to enable snapshots on a btrfs root file system on a transactional server?

Tags: opensuse, btrfs, snapshot

I recently had to reinstall my OppenSuSE Leap 15.5 based home server after a severe crash. The installer suggested me the "transactional server" option. But once the system was again ready to use, I found out that it was no longer possible to add a new package:

```bash
valen:~ # transactional-update pkg install  afio-2.5.1-lp154.39.1.x86_64.rpm
Checking for newer version.
transactional-update 4.1.0 started
Options: pkg install afio-2.5.1-lp154.39.1.x86_64.rpm
ERROR: no snapshots for root file system configured!
transactional-update finished
```

I got the same error message when trying to perform a system update with YaST. The problem is: The root file system is read-only, which prevents me from creating snapshots! At least I get an error message like this when trying to do so:

```bash
valen:~ # snapper -c root create-config /
Creating config file failed (creating btrfs subvolume .snapshots failed).
```

The respective checkbox in YaST is disabled BTW.

Changing the `/etc/fstab` entry of `/` (replacing `ro` with `defaults`) and rebooting does NOT help. Neither does using the `btrfs` utility to make `/` writable:

```bash
valen:~ # btrfs property set -tf / ro false
ERROR: object is not compatible with property: ro
```

This is how my file system looks like now:

```
││Gerät          │Größenlimit│Refer. Größe│Exkl. Größe│Mountpoint     ││   
││───Btrfs 0p1   │           │            │           │/              ││   
|| ├──@/opt      │           │            │           │/opt           ││   
││ ├──@/root     │           │            │           │/root          ││   
││ ├──@/tmp      │           │            │           │/tmp           ││   
││ ├──@/usr/local│           │            │           │/usr/local     ││   
││ └──@/var      │           │            │           │/var           ││
```

So my system is like a snake biting its own tail:

1. `/` was set up without snapshots by the installer. I don't know where I could have switched on snapshots in the whole process.
2. I can't update my system with snapshots turned off.
3. The docs say that I can add snapshots to existing `btrfs` volumes at any time. This does not work because of `/` being read-only, though.
4. There is apparently no way to make a read-only `btrfs` volume writeable, not even for adding a subvolume.
5. When a root filesystem on a transactional server makes no sense without snapshots, why does OpenSuSE's installer create it **without** snapshot support?

So: What can I do to circumvent the write protection of `/` in order to turn on snapshots without having to reinstall the whole system? I've thought about storing the snapshots on a writable subvolume like `/opt/.snapshots`, but I haven't found out how to do this.